# Link sql master to properties table then represent a prop value as a column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have a master object and properties table, object may have 0...n "random" properties. I want to link a master and certain props as a column.

How would you do it? This is my current solution, it works but may have a performance issues(?) later in the future.

```
Select v.code 
 ,(select value from properties where server_id=v.server_id and code=v.code and name='propx') as 'propx'
 ,(select value from properties where server_id=v.server_id and code=v.code and name='propy') as 'propy'
From masterobj v
Where 
    v.server_id='001'
    and (v.starttime between '2019-11-01 00:00:00' and '2019-11-15 23:59:59')
Order by v.starttime asc;
```

Mockup of data view

```
masterobj table
001  abc001  2019-11-01 13:01:00
001  abc002  2019-11-01 13:02:00
001  abc003  2019-11-01 13:03:00
001  abc004  2019-11-01 13:04:00
001  abc005  2019-11-01 13:05:00
001  abc901  2019-05-14 09:01:00
properties table
001  abc001  propx  128
001  abc001  propy  64
001  abc001  temp   1
001  abc002  temp   1
001  abc003  temp   0
001  abc003  propx  32
001  abc004  propy  20
Query Results
code    propx propy
abc001  128   64
abc002  
abc003  32
abc004        20
abc005
```

Comment: Skip the sub-queries, do left joins instead.

Comment: @jarlh You mean I left link a prop table two times with specific property name as a row filter and `p1.value as 'propx', p2.value as ' propy'`  columns?

Comment: Yes, do like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested this is a query with multiple left joins to a same table.

```
Select v.code, p1.value as 'propx', p2.value as 'propy'
From masterobj v
  Left Join properties p1 On (v.server_id=p1.server_id and v.code=p1.code and p1.name='propx')
  Left Join properties p2 On (v.server_id=p2.server_id and v.code=p2.code and p2.name='propy')
Where 
  v.server_id='001'
  and (v.starttime between '2019-11-01 00:00:00' and '2019-11-15 23:59:59')
Order by v.starttime asc;
```